# SOQL to get previous months records till date

Tags: apex, soql, custom-field

I have a requirement where I need to fetch records from Previous 3 months to Today. When I tried using Last_n_Months :2 binding, I can only retrieve previous months records excluding current month.

Can anyone please help me with this Query.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add with or condition `THIS_MONTH`
eg.

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate = LAst_N_Months:2 or CreatedDate = THIS_MONTH
```

Comment: Thank you Rahul. But when I query using the above given soql, I am recieveing records from 2017, 12th month. I can only get correct records when I hardcode viz., Processing_MONTH__C IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12). Please help

Comment: @Sastri can paste the query you are using now?

Comment: @Sastri Are you sure, you used the same query? I tried it in my dev org and its working as expected.

Comment: My bad...I have tried this in my other org and it is working fine. Thank you Rahul for this effort. Cheers!

Comment: @Sastri Welcome, Happy Coding!!

Comment: Rahul, can you please help me with my other issue here...
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244649/date-format-in-saql

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87513/discussion-between-sastri-and-rahul-gawale).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Date today = System.today();
Date last_n_month = today.addMonths(-3);
List<sObject> list_sobj = [select id from sObject_API_Name where CreatedDate >=: last_n_month AND CreatedDate <=: today order by CreatedDate DESC];
```

Or:

```
List<Lead> list_sobj = [select id,CreatedDate from Lead where CreatedDate >= Last_N_Months:3 AND CreatedDate <= today order by CreatedDate DESC];
for(lead s:list_sobj){
    System.debug(s);
}
```