# Date format in SAQL

Tags: einstein-analytics, saql, data-set

I have a requirement in **Wave Analytics** where I need to fetch records from Previous year when current year is completed. I have a field named Processing Year. It now fetches 2017 records which we have hard coded. But when we move to 2019, it need to fetch 2018 records. I have tried lot of options but nothing seems to be worked out.

Something like Current Year-1 will work. 
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you gone through [**saql date functions**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_saql.meta/bi_dev_guide_saql/bi_saql_functions_date.htm)

Comment: Hello Reshma...Yes I did but I didnt find required solution for the Issue.
I tried it with ["previous year"..] it didnt work 
It worked only when Hardcoded as 2017.
I need records of 2018 to be fetched when we enter 2019.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to get previous year records?
Is it by using Previous year or last year?
Nothing seems to work  for me

Answer (score 2):

Simply use 1 year ago as below. Assuming you will replace dataset and related date field name below:

```
q = load "Opportunity_SFDC";
q = filter q by date('CloseDate_Year', 'CloseDate_Month', 'CloseDate_Day') in ["1 year ago".."1 year ago"];
q = foreach q generate 'AccountId' as 'AccountId', 'CloseDate' as 'CloseDate',  'AccountId.Name' as 'AccountId.Name', 'Amount' as 'Amount', 'Probability' as 'Probability';
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Ayub. This one worked. Now I can able to retrieve 2017 records without hardcoding. I have a doubt here
Will this pull all the 2018's records when the year moves to 2019 or only jan 2018's records as it is set to one year ago

Comment: Lets wait for Jan 2019...please keep posted in either cases....